# Set shipping address for a quote

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping, quote, shipping-address

I want to set shipping address for a particular quote.

I load quote:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
```

I load address from a customer model:

```
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);
```

after that i want to set shipping address by this code:

```
$quote->setShippingAddress($addressId)->save();
```

but setShippingAddress method returns me an error:

**Internal Error. Please see log for details**

I have no idea how to resolve that.

Comment: What does it say in the log ?

Comment: 'Internal Error. Please see log for details.
in File: /var/www/html/magentoce/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
in Line:196 <end of log>

something wrong with the API ? "ouside" the API it looks that it works...

Answer (score 1):

According to your error:

```
var/www/html/magentoce/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php in Line:196
```

Which corresponds to that code:

```
if ($this->_extensionLoaded()) {
            throw new SoapFault($code, $message);
        }
```

Where `$this->_extensionLoaded` is the following:

```
protected function _extensionLoaded()
    {
        return class_exists('SoapServer', false);
    }
```

It looks like the problem is caused by the fact that you don't have SOAP installed/enabled on your server.

Comment: I don't thinks so.. if I remove method setShippingAddres it works and others my API methods works well. Strange :(